# Print EPS file at original size but changed position

Tags: printing, cups, postscript, lp, lpr

I'd like to print EPS files, ensuring they print at their original size. I found out that my default document viewer, Okular from KDE, will always scale to fit size, and I can't seem to find a way to disable this. I guess I could use some other UI, so answers in that direction are welcome as well. Next I tried `lpr` from Cups. It does print the EPS at original scale in the bottom left corner of the page, but unfortunately it does not take page margins into account.

Is there some tool to add margins to an EPS file, or some command line option to `lp` or `lpr` to move the position of the printed result on the page?

Comment: There are eps transform tools, that is what eps was designed for. I can not remember the names of the tools.